# Is this phrase true according to our philosophy?

Tags: scripture, philosophy

We know about a phrase given by Algernon Sidney which has faced controversies in the West but it's very popular too. It is:

> God helps those who help themselves.

Earlier people used to say that

> Leave that to god, he will take care.

But now people say that god helps those who help themselves.

While this is a good initiative to make people believe in themselves and not fully dependent on god (like never doing any duty and using god's name as a mere excuse by saying that god is there to help)

But my question is, is this type of thing present in our philosophy? I want answers with scriptural references for either of the two cases,i.e., Yes or No.

P.S. **IMO** I think that in our philosophy, god is not biased towards someone. I mean to say that he would also help the people who **cannot** help themselves if the devotion is true. In a nutshell, he looks for the devotion and helps all.

Comment: brahma sutras 2.1.34 - Bhagavan is neither partial (if you don't ask for help, and don't refuse help, and help yourself, he helps you), nor cruel (helps those who ask for help, doesn't help those who refuse help)

Comment: Thank you @mar  I think it's similar to what I told in question.

Comment: Both are true. The first sentence is true because God manifests as intellect, knowledge & strength internally & as time externally to aid the soul & applies in general case.The 2nd statement applies oly in the case of those people who have given off their sense of 'I' & 'mine' by completely surrendering to God's will.